# Trying to install ubuntu 16 on new PC - 2.5 hours already?

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, 64-bit

I just bought Intel i5-7500 with 8GB ram and 1TB disk and installing Ubuntu trough USB stick.
It already passed the 2.5 hours mark and still telling me, it downloads packages. I already chose the media packages to download without the updates.

Should it take so long to install? 
I also see Skip button, Should I skip it?

Comment: It shouldn't take more then 20 minutes. Have you checked the installation media for errors?

Comment: Nope, I am suspicious about the internet connection. It struggles to open even Google.com when I open the browser at the installation screen.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a network problem. Are you using DSL?

Comment: Well. I think it is still ADSL. We recently put ZTE router with wifi antennas. But the basic I think it is still DSL based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the MTU setting for your DSL connection.

**For DSL, a common MTU setting is 1492. Just go ahead and try this value first and see if your web sites are now accessible.**

To determine the correct setting, start with all MTU settings = 1500 and VPN = off. (VPN requires different testing).

In terminal:

```
ping [-c count] [-M do] [-s packet_size] [host]
```

The options used are:

- `c count`: number of times to ping
- `M hint`: Select Path MTU Discovery strategy.  may be either `do` (prohibit fragmentation, even local one), `want` (do PMTU discovery, fragment locally when packet size is large), or `dont` (do not set DF flag).
- `s packet_size`: Specifies the number of data bytes to be sent.

You should always start at 1472 and work your way down by 10 each time. Once you get a reply, go up by 1 until you get a fragmented packet. Take that value (last good value) and add 28 to the value to account for the various TCP/IP headers. Eg. let's say that 1452 was the proper packet size (where you first got an ICMP reply to your ping). The actual MTU size would be 1480, which is the optimum for the network we're working with.

```
ping -c 4 -M do -s 1472 8.8.8.8 # this will probably show fragmentation

ping -c 4 -M do -s 1462 8.8.8.8 # may show fragmentation

ping -c 4 -M do -s 1452 8.8.8.8 # no fragmentation?

ping -c 4 -M do -s 1453 8.8.8.8 # still no fragmentation?
```

reference: [How to determine the proper MTU size with ICMP pings](http://muzso.hu/2009/05/17/how-to-determine-the-proper-mtu-size-with-icmp-pings)

Comment: Tried ctrl+alt+T, it doesn't open terminal. How do I open it while in installation screen?

Comment: Tried 1500, 1492, 1472, no difference. Does it require restart? :D But I have to cancel the current installation

Comment: You set the MTU in the network script that you see when you pull down the network icon in the top panel. Change AUTO or 1500 to 1492.

Comment: Oh yeah... you'll probably have to at least reconnect to your wired/wireless network... or maybe even restart network-manager. And yes... your current installation isn't going anywhere. Cancel it. Set the MTU. See if you can connect to Google. Then install from scratch.

Comment: Yup, set to 1492, disconnected, reconnected. Now it loads Google :) Have to wait a bit, hopefully the installation will get some boost.

Comment: @Vlad status please

Comment: @Vlad so the MTU fixed your problem, yes? The installation completed, yes?

Comment: :) Ah installed and already using. Recently installed updates and now the Display fixed itself, thanks